# Irrationality of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)}$

Tags: irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta

I was looking at the following series $$S = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n-1)}$$ which WA says that it converges to some number (WA1: [2.18401](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NSum%5B1%2F%28Sqrt%5Bn%5D%20%28n%20-%201%29%29%2C%20%7Bn%2C%202%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D), WA2: [2.0839...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%281%2F%28sqrt%28n%29%28n-1%29%29%29)). I noticed that it is (almost) equal to $$\sum_{p=3,5,...}^\infty \zeta\left(\frac{p}{2}\right) = \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + \zeta\left(\frac{5}{2}\right) + \cdots,$$ i.e., sum of "all halves" (from 3/2) of Rieman zeta functions.

Here is my thinking:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n-1)} = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{3}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{5}{2}+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{7}{2}+\dots$$
Sum it over $n$ from 2 to $\infty$, you get e.g. for the first part $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}},$ which is almost $\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$, except that the summation does not start at $n=1$. To fix this, I do
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}=\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) - 1.$

Thus, I conclude that $$\sum_{p=3,5,...}^\infty \left(\zeta\left(\frac{p}{2}\right) - 1\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\zeta\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) - 1\right)= \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n - 1)}.$$
It is also known (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) that
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\zeta(n) - 1\right) = 1$.
We can thus combine those sums, leading to
$$\sum_{p=3}^\infty\left(\zeta\left(\frac{p}{2}\right) - 1\right)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n-1)} + 1$$

My question is. If it is correct, is this identity known? If so, can we conclude that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n-1)}$ is an irrational number (sum of square roots "feels" like an irrational number) and thus also the sum of "Riemann halves" is irrational number?

Also, is there something known about the $\sum_{p=1,3,5,...}^\infty \zeta\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)$? Its convergence, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you write the general term as $\dfrac1{\sqrt n(n-1)}$ ?

Comment: Convergence of the series in the title is trivial. Compare with $\sum \frac1 {n^{3/2}}$

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Yes, that's the same. I just like the square root to be in the numerator.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I modified the title. I am more interested in if the number is irrational (since, yes,, indeed it converges to something).Please, read the rest of the question.

Comment: I get almost the same values for the given series and for the series with $\zeta$ function, but these values are $2.18400947$ then the digits are different, but this may be because *Mathematica* has approximate. Look here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NSum%5B1%2F%28Sqrt%5Bn%5D+%28n+-+1%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+Infinity%7D%5D

Comment: @Raffaele Wow. Now, that is interesting:)

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \zeta \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 n+1)\right)$ does not converge. How did you get the idea to link the given series to this monster? $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 n+1)\right)-1\right)$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)}=\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{n}+1}+\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{n}-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the question if it is known: It seems that the same equality has been mentioned lately in [The Spiral of Theodorus and Sums ofZeta-values at the Half-integers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.119.09.779?seq=1)